# Adding information on each page in "longtable"

Tags: longtable

At some point in my document I'm using a "longtable", which is spread among different pages. What I'd love to do is to add some text on each of these pages, possibly on the top of the table. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

longtable offers the command `\endhead` for specifying a heading which will be repeated on each page. If you want a different heading on the first page of the longtable one can define a `\endfirsthead` additionally.

Take a look at the longtable package documentation for further explanation and example code.